# Accessor that returns value vs accessor that returns reference?

Tags: objective-c, accessor

From my understanding both of the following getter methods reference the actual object.
So what is the difference between the two?
When and why would you want to use the second getter method?

```
- (MyObject *)myObject
{
   return _myObject;
}

- (void)getMyObject:(MyObject **)myObject
{
   if (!myObject)
   {
      *myObject = _myObject;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not use the second one.

**Unless** you like confusing people/yourself at a later date by not following the standard conventions.

It would make more sense if there was another piece of data that could also be returned for example look at `NSManagedObjectContext`

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error
```

The important result of the method is `YES`/`NO` did it save, but then we can also get an `NSError` object to inspect if there was an error.

Comment: What Paul said;  you should *never* have a return-by-reference method *unless* that method either returns success/fail and passes an error reference in the failure case (standard Cocoa error handling pattern -- note that some methods will return success/fail and also a pass-by-reference value of a different type) *or* the method returns multiple pass-by-reference return values.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C, an "object" is a C pointer, so an object value is actually already the same as a structure reference (an opaque structure with hidden fields if you want the code to be portable between Objective C runtimes).

So there is no "versus".

YouR first example is both.

There are special situations when an algorithm needs a reference to a reference, or a pointer to a pointer, but not very commonly.  That would be your second example.